# Tips for creating multi directional scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

Im am trying to create a TV guide similar to SKY TV guide app on the iPad and similar experience to the ShowYou iPad app. The user can scroll either horizontally or vertically. The horizontal scroll will show more programmes whilst a vertical scroll will allow more channels to be scrolled.

```
          12am|        1am|          2am| 

channel 1     | example | example2      |
channel 2     | example 3  |
channel 3            | example 4        |
.....
channel 20
```

Hopefully the diagram makes some sense.

The time values will also change to represent the times of the programme as the user scrolls horizontally.

Are there any good example of this sort of framework available or could you give me any tips of where to look to gain a better understanding of how to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably done with 3 scroll views. The left most only scrolls up/down. The top only scrolls left/top, and of course the main one scrolls all ways.

You need to setup a delegate for the main scroll view that listens to scroll position changes. For each event, update the scroll position of the other two scroll views.

Do the same for the other two scroll views. If the left scroll view scrolls, update the main scroll view to match. If the top scroll view scrolls, update the main scroll view.